# setting password with system.setPassword() does change security token as well?

Tags: administration, change-password, reset-password

I am setting a password of an existing user, is it possible that setting this password will reset the security token as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Chirag. I confirm that setting password with system.setPassword() does change the security token and also send it to the user through Email, I have tried it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it does.  If you are trying to use setPassword() with an API user, consider creating a custom API profile with the "Password Never Expires" permission turned on.